# Liferay: How to add cookie from portlet

Tags: java, cookies, liferay

I trying to add cookie from portlet using

```
HttpServletResponse response=PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(renderResponse);
Cookie cookie=new Cookie("abc","123");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

But when i am trying to print value for this cookie i am not able to find this cookie.
Can anyone suggest me the solution for this?

Comment: How are you getting cookies? Either by request.getCookies() or other way?

Comment: Cookie[] cookies=renderRequest.getCookies();

Comment: Probably, cookies will be available through HTTPServletRequest so try to extract it from simple request object.

Comment: i tried httpservletrequest also .. but not getting new added cookie..

Comment: Make sure, your browser is allowed to create and store cookies. The pattern you are trying is fine.

Comment: i checked that ...browser setting are okay..
do you know any other way to implement it..?please paste it if you know..
i will also check othr solutions

Answer (score 1):

Not so easy discover how to use a cookie in your portlet,

This cose sample is ok and is written within the portlet render code.
Use the `RenderResponse`, not the `HttpServletResponse`.

```
import com.liferay.util.CookieUtil;

Cookie cookie = new Cookie("name", value);

renderResponse.addProperty(cookie);
```

And to read the cookie from the request:

```
HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(
                portletRequest);

orderCartNumber = CookieUtil.get(request, "name");
```

bye

Comment: Cookie cookie=new Cookie("abc","Value");      

  renderResponse.addProperty(cookie);
  System.out.println("found "+renderRequest.getProperty("abc"));  --------output: null            





  Cookie[] cookies=renderRequest.getCookies();           

  if (cookies != null) 
  {        
 
   for(int i=0; i<cookies.length; i++) 
   {       

    System.out.println("cookies "+cookies[i].getName()+" values"+cookies[i].getValue());

    }
   }
  }
                       

I am not getting newly defined cookie

Comment: I edited my response to complete with the way i use to read the cookie from the request. this combination works well in my project based on Lifeary 6.1.1